# React Native debugging

Tags: react-native

I am trying to debug this error:

**Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:71:16 in error
- node_modules\fbjs\lib\warning.js:33:20 in printWarning
- ... 25 more stack frames from framework internals**

I have no way of finding out which file or line number is causing the problem.

My javascript says its compiled 100%.

How would I know which file is causing the problem?

Comment: react-native-debugger may give some clue. But I know the frustrating feeling when that kind of errors with obsolete stack traces appears.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a debugger on your browser. You can add console.log() calls to check variable values/see where your code breaks, and the logs will show on your browser.

If you are on the iOS simulator:

1. run the iOS simulator
2. enter command + D

[image]

3. select "Debug JS remotely"
4. that should open http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ on your browser
5. use the inspect functionality of your browser. If you are on chrome, you right click -> inspect -> go to "Console" tab
6. your console.log() outputs should be there together with some other warnings/errors

[image]